# In Angular 2 I'm trying to get @canActivate to work for my routes but doesnt seem to work

Tags: angularjs, angular

In Angular 2 I'm trying to get @canActivate to work for my routes but doesnt seem to work.

**This is the version of my router (Not sure if it works with this version):** 
"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",

**This some of my app.ts file:**

```
import {AuthGuard} from './interceptor';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app',
  providers: [RouterOutlet, RouterOutletMap, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, HTTP_BINDINGS],
  template: `

    <div class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
    </div>   
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
  { path: '/', component: Home, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '/home', component: Home, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
])
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(){

  }
}
```

**This is my authGuard service:**

```
import { Injectable, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: 'authguard'
})

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular is at version 2.0.0-rc.4. The router is at version V3-beta.2. Please ensure you have the latest versions.

`@Routes` is only for older router versions
`canActivate: [AuthGuard]` is only for the newest versions

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/', component: Home, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '/home', component: Home, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
])
```

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html for more details about how to use the new router.

Comment: is there anything similar i can use for this version of the router?

Comment: You can implement `CanActivate` on the component where you want to use it. I'd strongly recommend to update. This router is deprecated and will not be updated or supported in any way.

Comment: how would I implement that? Could you add an example?

Comment: I understand. You should be aware though that all time you invest in the old router is wasted. Search for `routerCanActivate`. Some related questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+canactivate+componentinstruction

Comment: Sorry, I'm not interested in investing time in question about the old router except for helping with upgrading.

Comment: I can try upgrading if you give me easy instructions. How would I do this for the router only?

Comment: I don't think there are easy instructions. These two routers are quite different. You'll need to read the doc I linked to in my answer and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: Whats the npm command to update my router version in my node packages?

Comment: Sorry, here you read the limitations of my knowledge. I use only Dart locally and TS only for Plunkers for SO answers. There should be questions with answers on SO though.